# Unresolved reference 'views' in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, web

```
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from crudapplication import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('emp', views.emp),
    path('show', views.show),
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit),
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update),
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.destroy),
]
```

1. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapplication.crudapplication'
   [program structure hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9WbY.png)

Comment: Show us settings.py **INSTALLED_APPS**

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crudapplication',
]

Answer (score 0):

```
from `.`crudapplication import views
```

You forgot Dot(.)

Comment: I add (.) but still not working, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapplication.crudapplication'

Comment: Show us settings.py INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crudapplication',
]

Comment: Run pip freeze and check Django is installed or not

Comment: I run pip freeze, Django is installed

Answer (score 0):

simply because they are on different packages. Try this approach:

1. Define the `urls.py` in your `crudapplication` then use `include` in your main `urls`

- In your crudapplication package, create `urls.py` with this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('emp/', views.emp),
    # the rest of your views..
]
```

- back to your webapplication's `urls.py`, insert following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('crudapplication.urls')) 
]
```

This will resolve the IDE error and solve the URLS routing. 
Note that, your current approach will throw IDE warning but i believe ur routing still works.